# Set default value in query when value is null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm running a really simple query, however for some of the results the value in one field is null. How can I set that value to "a string" if its value is null?

Something like

```
SELECT RegName,
    RegEmail,
    RegPhone,
    RegOrg,
    RegCountry,
    DateReg,
    (Website IS NULL? 'no website' : Website) AS WebSite
FROM RegTakePart
WHERE Reject IS NULL
```

It will be running on a sql server 2005

thanks

Comment: Look at the `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` functions.

Comment: Thanks everyone I'll accept the answer as soon as it will allow me

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the following:

```
SELECT RegName,
       RegEmail,
       RegPhone,
       RegOrg,
       RegCountry,
       DateReg,
       ISNULL(Website,'no website')  AS WebSite 
FROM   RegTakePart 
WHERE  Reject IS NULL
```

or as, @Lieven noted:

```
SELECT RegName,
       RegEmail,
       RegPhone,
       RegOrg,
       RegCountry,
       DateReg,
       COALESCE(Website,'no website')  AS WebSite 
FROM   RegTakePart 
WHERE  Reject IS NULL
```

The dynamic of COALESCE is that you may define more arguments, so if the first is null then get the second, if the second is null get the third etc etc...

Comment: take with ISNULL if you migrate to MySQL. The sintax there is different
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: Not relevant to this example, but still noteworthy, the downside of COALESCE is that it expands to a case statement, so `COALESCE((SELECT Col FROM T), 'No Value')`, expands to `CASE WHEN (SELECT Col FROM T) IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT Something FROM Table) ELSE 'No Value' END` meaning the subquery is executed twice if the result is not null. ISNULL does not exhibit this behaviour. An upside of coalesce is that it is in the ANSII Standard, ISNULL() is not.

Answer (score 11):

As noted above, the coalesce solution is preferred. As an added benefit, you can use the coalesce against a "derived" value vs. a selected value as in:

```
SELECT
       {stuff},
       COALESCE( (select count(*) from tbl where {stuff} ), 0 )  AS countofstuff
FROM
       tbl
WHERE
       {something}
```

Using "iif" or "case" you would need to repeat the inline whereas with coalesce you do not and it allows you to avoid a "null" result in that return...

Comment: Wrapping the first argument of the `COALESCE` with `()` is very important, or the query will not compile. Thank you for this

Answer (score 9):

Use `CASE`:

```
SELECT regname, 
       regemail, 
       regphone, 
       regorg, 
       regcountry, 
       datereg, 
       CASE 
         WHEN website IS NULL THEN 'no website' 
         ELSE website 
       END AS WebSite 
FROM   regtakepart 
WHERE  reject IS NULL
```

or `COALESCE`:

```
....
COALESCE(website, 'no website') AS WebSite 
....
```

Answer (score 2):

You just use `ISNULL(website, 'yourstring')`.

So, your query will be like:

```
SELECT RegName,
    RegEmail,
    RegPhone,
    RegOrg,
    RegCountry,
    DateReg,
    ISNULL(website, 'no website') AS WebSite
FROM RegTakePart
WHERE Reject IS NULL
```

Comment: No matter what answer you choose, they will all work. `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` are both solutions.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid some problems to other users :

**Problem 1 + Solution :**

If you are planning to use the `ISNULL` function with an Access Database, be aware of the fact that the `ISNULL` function implemented in Access is differrent from the SQL Server implementation.

Access `ISNULL` function always returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
So you have to use a custom `IIF` function around your `ISNULL`usage.

**Problem 2 + Solution :**

Moreover, if you wish to use the same field name as Alias for your column, this could lead the Access Database Engine to inform you that there is a "**circular reference**" to the field.

So if you need to use the same field name as Alias, you just have to add the table name before the field name. (example : You have to use  `RegTakePart.Website` instead of simply `Website`). This way, you can freely use `Website` as Alias name for your column.

The global working (and tested) SQL query to avoid these 2 problems is the following one :

```
SELECT RegName,
    RegEmail,
    RegPhone,
    RegOrg,
    RegCountry,
    DateReg,
    IIF(RegTakePart.Website IS NULL, 'no website, RegTakePart.Website) AS Website
FROM RegTakePart
WHERE Reject IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the COALESCE function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

```
SELECT RegName,RegEmail,RegPhone,RegOrg,RegCountry,DateReg,COALESCE(Website, 'no website') AS WebSite FROM RegTakePart WHERE Reject IS NULL
```